# how to make the element contains '$' char as key, and behind the key's numbers as a List?

Tags: scala

there is a Array ,how to make the element contains '$' char as key, and behind the key's numbers as a List

```
val a = Array("$A", 1234, "$B", 123, 4, 5)
```

expected:

```
Map("$A"->List(1234),"$B"->List(123,4,5)))
```

thx for all answerer, as below is my finally code:

```
a.toList.tails.collect {
  case (key: String) :: rest if key.contains('$') => (key, rest.takeWhile(!_.toString.contains('$')))
}.toMap
```

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `foldLeft` (assuming `Array[Any]` as input):

```
a.foldLeft(List.empty[(String, List[Int])]){
    case (acc, el: String) if el.head == '$' => 
      (el -> List.empty[Int]) :: acc 
    case (acc, el) => 
      val updatedHead = acc.head._1 -> (Integer.parseInt(el.toString) :: acc.head._2)
      updatedHead :: acc.tail
}.toMap.mapValues(_.reverse)
```

`reverse` is needed because `::` (adding element to the beginning of a List) is faster than adding element to the end, but `List[Int]` gets reversed this way.

Another option is tail-recursive call to [`span`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#span(p:A=>Boolean):(List[A],List[A])).

P.S. Be careful, `Map` doesn't guarantee insertion order (even for keys, regardless it's iterator), so you can't use it for accumulator (you can't get `keys.last` element from it):

```
scala> (1 to 10).toList.foldLeft(Map.empty[Int, Int]){case (acc, x) => acc + (x -> x)}.keys.toList
res23: List[Int] = List(5, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)
```

However, you can use `ListMap`, but `keys.last` is slower (linear time) than `list.head` (constant time).

P.S.2 Keep in mind that your `a.toList.tails.collect...` version revisits some elements 2-3 times: 1 additional time when collect skips integer, 1 additional time when takeWhile detects end of sequence, so it might affect performance.

Comment: Just for clarification, why not using a Map initially (see my answer)?

Comment: @thwiegan `Map` doesn't preserve insertion order (except for small collections like 3 elements), that `keys` iterator is actually `Set` inside. That's why I always prefer `List`. There is a workaround (ListMap), however it has its overheads over regular `Map`

Comment: @thwiegan so you can't use `keys.last` on a bare `Map` (`HashMap`)

Comment: @thwiegan also `keys.last` takes linear time in `ListMap`

Comment: I see, thanks for the info :) Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a simple fold:

```
val a = Array("$A", 1234, "$B", 123, 4, 5)

a.foldLeft((Map.empty[String, List[Int]], Option.empty[String])) {
  case ((map, _), ele: String) if ele.startsWith("$") => 
    (map + (ele -> List[Int]()), Some(ele))
  case ((map, Some(lastKey)), ele: Int) =>
    (map + (lastKey -> (map(lastKey) :+ ele)), Some(lastKey))
} _1
```

Results in a `Map($A -> List(1234), $B -> List(123, 4, 5))`

Folding over the elements in the array. Creating a new list and saving key for later use if element contains '$'. Adding element to list at `lastKey` in case of `Int`. Taking first element of the resulting tuple, to get rid of the `lastKey`.

Answer (score 0):

- first find the index of `$`. example `List(("$A", 0), ("$B", 2))`
- and find the range of each `$`. `(("$A", 0, 2), ("$B", 2, 6))`
- then slice the array with above `$` range

Here's an example,

```
val input = Array("$A", 1234, "$B", 123, 4, 5)

val index$Elems = input.zipWithIndex.map {case (elem, index) =>
  if (elem.toString.startsWith("$")) elem.toString -> index
} filter(!_.isInstanceOf[BoxedUnit])

val groupElems = index$Elems.zipWithIndex.map {
  case (kv: (String, Int), index: Int) if index != index$Elems.length - 1 =>
    Tuple3(kv._1, kv._2, index$Elems(index + 1).asInstanceOf[(String, Int)]._2)

  case (keyvalue: (String, Int), index) if index == index$Elems.length - 1 =>
    Tuple3(keyvalue._1, keyvalue._2, input.length)

} map { elems: (String, Int, Int) =>
  Map(elems._1 -> input.slice(elems._2 + 1, elems._3).toList)
}
```

Tests

```
groupElems.head("$A") shouldBe List(1234)
groupElems.last("$B") shouldBe List(123, 4, 5)
```